# New Relic unable to load properly (Android) using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I am trying to work on New Relic using [this
link](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-monitoring/mobile-monitoring-installation/android/installing-android-apps-ant).

I had followed the same instructions that are given on that link, but every time I get the same error.

[image]

I also tried this also https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-monitoring/mobile-monitoring-installation/android/troubleshooting-eclipse-configurations

I also have used **jdk1.8.0_05**. and **eclipse juno** with latest SDK 23.0.2.
please some one help me to resolve this.

Comment: Can you try showing the console output from Eclipse using the         -consoleLog startup option? This would be done in the same way you pass the -vm option when specifying the correct JDK.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Eventually found this: https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/installing-eclipse/6793
Basically, it doesn't work with Eclipse Luna yet. It also doesn't work with Indigo, which just leaves Juno and Kepler.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the link given by @rockgecko.

Points to remember:-

- Add the absolute path upto "**javaw.exe**" after the suffix "**-vm**"
- In eclipse, Add the Standard Environment under JAVA/JRE, do put path of JDK there & it should be upto JDK folder only and do remember to active it instead of previous JRE option after adding it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in eclipse juno properties in target section after eclipse.exe

-vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\javaw.exe"

and set PATH variable like this way
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin;.

in environment variables in your system properties.

Hope it will work for you.